# Excon Error :: BadRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone know where this error is coming from? I am new to AWS, and believe it may be from there?

> Excon::Errors::BadRequest in UsersController#update Expected(200) <=>
>   Actual(400 Bad Request) excon.error.response :body => "\n`IncompleteBody`The
>   request body terminated
>   unexpectedly9C1EC55648FB3ED91vv/2RNBp9egndYkTjzbCBgQu0jk3AjpAZffR+firWM4Yzd6ilQxJnfKwKZVK8+N"
>   :headers => { "Connection" => "close" "Content-Type" =>
>   "application/xml" "Date" => "Tue, 21 Apr 2015 18:13:09 GMT" "Server"
>   => "AmazonS3" "x-amz-id-2" => "1vv/2RNBp9egndYkTjzbCBgQu0jk3AjpAZffR+firWM4Yzd6ilQxJnfKwKZVK8+N"
>   "x-amz-request-id" => "9C1EC55648FB3ED9" } :local_address =>
>   "10.151.101.107" :local_port => 51335 :reason_phrase => "Bad Request"
>   :remote_ip => "54.231.232.1" :status => 400 :status_line => "HTTP/1.1
>   400 Bad Request\r\n"

Here is my UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def update
     if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
       flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
       redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
     else
       flash[:error] = "Invalid user information"
       redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
     end
   end

   private
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
   end
 end
```

Comment: You should provide more information about the corresponding controller method.

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen as well I found out by pointing to the wrong region.  I was accidentally pointed at us-west-2 but my S3 bucket was us-east-1.  I changed my Fog settings and things are much happier now.  Leaving this here to hopefully help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have a malformed body in your POST. Inspect the data you are passing in the body.  Are you passing in a line break `\n`? If so, be sure to properly encode it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the cause of this specific problem, but "IncompleteBody" can sometimes be due to Excon chunking the request, which seems to terminate the S3 connection in some cases.

Try adding an initializer with the following code:

```
if ENV["RAILS_GROUPS"] == 'assets'
  Excon.defaults[:nonblock] = false
end
```

Source: [Handling S3 IncompleteBody error when using asset_sync gem](http://sortedarray.com/handling-s3-incompletebody-error-when-using-asset_sync-gem/)